# How to access scene camera rotation data in a context driver in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, drivers

This question refers to the feature introduced here: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/c26566ad

The path listed in this link, camera.matrix_world[3][0], allows for accessing the scene camera's X location transforms, and changing the [0] to [1] and [2] allows access to the Y and Z location transforms. In geometry nodes, I'm using these as a context driver to control the values of a Vector node.

However, I don't know how to access its rotation transforms. (Considering the many options for rotation, such as XYZ Euler and Quaternions, I imagine the path would look a little different). I also assume that it would give the value in radians and not degrees, but that's all right.

I'd appreciate some guidance on how to access the camera's rotation via drivers, specifically in Geometry Nodes (as I have been doing for the location).

Comment: Why a Driver? Have you tried the node `Object Info`?

Comment: This is using the new context drivers. This allows me to access the active scene camera even if it changes with marker-bindings, which is not possible with object info.

Comment: In which version were those drivers introduced? To me this looks like they are still in development, as I see links to bug reports regarding 3.6.0 Alpha... on this site we are focusing on officially released Blender versions, since alpha, beta versions etc. are still subject to change and this is no developers' site.

Comment: It's in 3.6. However, there shouldn't be any significant developmental changes at this point for this feature, and since this question is just about the RNA path of a certain bit of data it's even more unlikely to change.

Comment: @Legoman Well, one significant change could be that there might come a node which can use this feature more easy...? Nodes change between versions as well.